# Check if uint16_t contains binary uin8_t

Tags: binary, contains

Suppose I have two bytes, `0xE1` and `0xE6`. These consecutive bytes where cut from a longer range of bits. Since the cutting point is not related to the actual byte values, I need to check whether these bytes contain another, say `0x3C`. Basically a binary string contains.

```
0xE1    0xE6
1110000111100110
     00111100     // It matches!
     0x3C
```

How do I algorithmically test this?

Comment: I don't think it being binary would make much difference, just run any old [string search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shift the word (2 bytes) to the right, get the lower byte and compare !

Play with it [here](http://ideone.com/IQIL1R)

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int contains(short twobytes, char onebyte)
{
    int i=0;
    for (; i<8; i++)
    {
        if (onebyte == ((twobytes >> i) & 0xFF))
          return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    if (contains(0xE1E6, 0x3C))
    {
        printf("YES!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("No :(\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a binary string... so any string search should work.  For example this simple C# snippet should work:

```
ushort s = 123;
byte b = 3;
//0000000001111011
string sBitString = Convert.ToString(s, 2).PadLeft(16,'0');
//00000011
string bBitString = Convert.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(8,'0');
//True, because the strings match at zero-based index 3 
bool result = sBitString.Contains(bBitString);
```

Of course, this particular implementation isn't the most performant - it'd be possible to write a more efficient solution with knowledge of bitwise operators - but as always this is dependant on your performance needs.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ushort s = 123;
    byte b = 3;
    int result = IndexOf(s, b);

    Console.ReadLine();
}

static int IndexOf(ushort s, byte b)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        //  First we shift the short down into a byte: (s >> (8 - i))
        //  This removes the 'right' bits.  We then do an 'and'  
        //  to remove any unnecessary 'left' bits.
        var shortSegment = (s >> (8 - i)) & 255;
        if (shortSegment == b) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

(Note:  ushort represents two bytes in C#, while a byte represents 1 byte).